# Application experienced internal error loading the SSL libraries in asp.net MVC and FileContentResult

Tags: excel, ssl, model-view-controller, warnings, filecontentresult

The MVC application am developing has feature to upload/download files that supports files of type- xls,xlsm,xlsx, doc,docx,pdf,msg etc.

Recently, the code for downloading the file got modified to return FileResult form action method instead of, giving link to the file in server. Given the code below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ShowFile()
{
   return new FileContentResult(FileBytes, mimeType);
}
```

The above code in windows7 machines throwing Microsoft Excel Security Warning popup with below message, But the code is working fine in windows 10 IE 11

```
The application experienced an internal error loading the SSL libraries
```

When the code modified as below, got the warning message stop displaying.

```
return this.File(response.FileBytes, mimeType, response.FileName);
```

Can someone help understand what actually causing the issue with returning the FileContentResult as response from the Action Result

Comment: Is there, by chance, more to the error?  Perhaps about a certificate?  (like [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e07aa2b7-abd4-4212-94b9-56cf73a91323/certificate-error-while-opening-excel-file?forum=officeitpro)?)

Comment: It is the same messages like in the link. No detail of any certificate specifically.